# A Javascript quiz about hoisting

Tags: javascript, hoisting

```
var d = 1;

(function(){
  d = '2'
  console.log(typeof d)
  function d() {
  }
})()

console.log(typeof d)
```

Could you explain why the second log prints out "number"?

```
var d = 1;

(function(){
  d = '2'
  console.log(typeof d)
})()

console.log(typeof d)
```

I tried to remove the function from the IIFE, and the result of second log becomes "string". I am very confused about it.

Answer (score 3):

The first code:

```
var d = 1;

(function(){
  d = '2'
  function d() {
  }
})()
```

because of function hoisting (function definitions are hoisted to the top of the containing scope - I think I worded that right), it's **identical** to

```
var d = 1;

(function(){
  function d() {
  }
  d = '2'
})()
```

Now, `d` inside the IIFE is declared locally, so the "global" `d` is irrelevant and untouched by `d='2'`

Comment: thanks, i was confused about this for a while)

Comment: @norbekoff - yeah, hoisting is *fun* !!